# Single exercises to improve kicking and punching power

Tags: muay-thai

I would like to improve my kicking as well as my punching in terms of power / strength. For kicking I would especially distinguish between teeps (front kicks) and low kicks. Which single exercise(s) would improve the kicking power accordingly for both kicks?

When it comes to punching it's probably a bit more diverse as jab & cross, hooks and uppercuts are very different from each other, I'd guess? However, which exercises would improve these?

An obvious way to improve above techniques is likely to just do them. Which I do. However, is there, for example, a physical exercise that has a great influence on their power?
I'm open for anything but I would like to get to know 1-2 very efficient methods, if there are any?

Comment: Doing your punches and kicks isn't "naive." It is a very important aspect of improving and becoming better at it.

Comment: Maybe "obvious approach" would have worked better than "naive approach"...

Comment: @rob74 Yeah, basically the point I was making. I'll edit that real quick and possibly fix any other errors.

Comment: You're right. I'm not a native speaker so I thought this term would be the same as a very close (or actually even the same) word in my mother language. Sorry, have to be more cautious in the future.

Comment: @Ben no problem. In English, I believe naive means immature or childish. Just try to keep that in mind for next time.

Answer (score 7):

It's as much technique and flexibility as it is strength. That being said, you need to look at the mechanism of action for each kick, and strengthen the muscles that control that action.

For the front kick, the basic muscles will be the abdominals for stability, hip flexors to raise the upper leg and the quadriceps to extend the leg out for the kick. The quadriceps are the large group of muscles that cover the front of the leg. Depending on the type of front kick (Ball or instep) the calves will come in to play.

Punches are going to be a little more involved, but the main motivators are going to be abdominals, chest (pectorals), and triceps which are the muscles at the back of the arm. With a proper technique punch, however, it's pretty much all the muscles from the feet up in various contributions.

All that being said, a good basic strength training program such as stronglifts 5x5, starting strength or similar will cover most of what you need. Squats (or a variant) for quads, deadlifts for hamstrings, bench press/dumbbell fly, tricep extensions, bicep curls should be the foundation of your program. If you are new to weights, absolutely recommend stronglifts or starting strength. Don't try to design your own until you have more experience.

Answer (score 4):

"Just do them" actually isn't as simple as that.

The biggest effect on your punches and kicks isn't how much muscle you have, but how much muscle (and body momentum) is recruited. In other words, technique.

The best way to build technique is to forget about power and speed. Instead, do your techniques smoothly, with minimum stress in your limbs. As you're doing it, focus on whether your hand or foot is following the shortest path to the target. Focus on whether your rear leg is being used to push into the technique. Focus on whether any rotation of your body is smooth and not hindered by your hips, knees, or foot position. Analyze the hell out of all of it.

Once you've got that, then sure, you can analyse whether any particular muscle groups can be improved on. But this is radically unlikely. It's virtually certain that if you feel your technique isn't powerful enough, the issue is with how you're doing it.

You describe this as naive. It would be naive if you carried on just doing what you're doing the same way and expecting a different result. The non-naive version is to keep doing it but analyse what you're not getting right and fix it.

And with all of this, you *must* do it without tension in your muscles. The main thing stopping your triceps extending your arm fast is your bicep. You need to drill the hell out of your movements in a relaxed way, so that they stay relaxed when you add power. Again, the naive way would be to keep going hard and expect to get better. You won't.

I've recently started a kickboxing-based style, after a background in Japanese styles. I'm currently in the process of completely rebuilding my footwork for how boxers move and punch, launching a cross from the ball of the back foot instead of the karate style of having your feet flat on the floor. So I feel your pain! :) but I know the process will pay dividends. It just needs me to drill the technique and be my own worst critic at picking up everything.

Answer (score 2):

What follows is meant to supplement some of what has already been written, and endorses an emphasis upon technique as primary, acknowledging significant gains can be made with appropriate high-specificity exercises. This answer relates to punches only, and describes transformative techniques I was taught by a student of biomechanics.

**Jabs**

Instead of trying to *push* your fist forward, instead imagine there's a rope tied around your wrist and that someone is *pulling* your fist away from you, towards the target.

Why it works (for me).

The jab is typically utilised as a fast, rangy punch; as a range-finder, a deterrent counter and as an outright offensive weapon. When beginners try to infuse this punch with power and speed, they tend to do at least four things wrong which hamper its effectiveness. A) They tense up, which slows the motion. B) They retract the punch before throwing it, which telegraphs the punch and almost doubles its execution time. C) They don't rotate the shoulders, losing invaluable range and considerably restricting power. D) They don't punch *through* the target, greatly reducing the impact of the strike.

When I began to imagine my fist being pulled forward, it became easier to keep my body relaxed until the moment of impact (increasing speed dramatically), the temptation to 'chamber' the jab disappeared (so my punches became far more difficult to read) and my punches grew longer (maximising my effective range and making it easier to avoid my opponent's attacks). At first, I neglected to punch through the target, but by learning to focus about a fist's length *beyond* the bag, my jabs soon grew much, much faster and heavier. They key is to tense at the moment of impact so that you maintain acceleration for as long as possible prior to impact, but simultaneously ensure your wrist is rigid enough upon hitting the bag to transfer your body weight properly 'through' it.

Another tip: Work on doubling and tripling your jab, being sure to retract it properly to your jaw every time, *as quickly as possible*. Studies have shown that training the negative motion of an explosive movement is highly beneficial to the positive motion. When you repeatedly throw the jab, the retraction/forward bounce effectively becomes a form of plyometric training which has long been recognised as one of the primary methods by which to achieve athletic explosiveness. Retraction speed of course also allows you to regain a defensive posture more quickly and increases the potential speed of your combinations.

You can add very light (1/2 - 1 kilo to start) dumbbells when shadow boxing if you wish, but exercise great caution with higher-resistance plyometrics. It is very easy to injure yourself and elbow hyperextension is a real danger. A safer alternative can be to use a loop of lightweight resistance band. Hold one end of the loop in each hand and wrap it around your back so that when you punch, the band adds resistance. Key to this form of training (or any highly motion-specific exercise when added resistance is used) is the maintaining of proper form. It is easy to let tired muscles fall into bad habits, and for your hard work to translate into the reinforcement of these bad habits, and into injury from poor form.

**Crosses**

The same principles and drills/exercises apply here, but there's one very useful and under-utilised aspect of technique which comes into play when transitioning between hands during combinations.

Imagine you are attached to the ground via a pole which extends through the top of your head, down through your neck and torso, to between your feet at the ground. In ideal circumstances, that pole represents the axis point around which your shoulders rotate when punching.

Many beginners throw one punch and retract it before launching with their opposite hand. Whilst this can be appropriate if during a fight you are throwing sporadic punches, if maximisation of power during combinations is the goal, the retraction of one hand should be accompanied by the forward thrust of the opposite hand. This is where the pole comes into play. Imagine throwing a jab with full extension, so that your shoulders rotate around the pole to be parallel with the line of the punch. Now, as you retract that punch, you will notice that you can allow your shoulders to operate relatively passively, rotating around the axis to throw a long cross, which is what many people do, emphasising the arms instead of the torso, losing a *lot* of power in the process. Instead, imagine pulling back firmly with your jab-side scapula and shoulder as you punch forward with the cross. You are (almost) doubling the force applied via the rotation of the shoulders when you do this, resulting in a quick performance gain. Note the aforementioned exercises with light dumbbells and resistance bands apply to crosses as well as jabs.